# How to forcefully delete files (system files)

Tags: filesystem, files, delete, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete/edit files from readonly filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31614/how-to-delete-edit-files-from-readonly-filesystem)

i have a memory card (MS-DOS file system I believe) which I want to delete ALL the files in it.
Even though I use `sudo rm -fr *` I still get

> Read-only file system

For the files in the memory card folder.
How do I remove all the files? (Or maybe just format it?)

Comment: Sometimes the memory cards have a tiny switch on the side to lock them as read-only, can you check and see if this is the issue? Also, be very careful deleting files with `sudo` and the `*` character, things can go very wrong very quickly if you mis-type anything.

Comment: No, the lock switch is in the right place, and this card is no longer functional (due to space) so, I can't really damage it more..

Comment: @ItayMoav  Have you tried putting it in a card-reader and formatting it with gnome-disk-utility?

Comment: Did it windows machine. This is actually a duplicate as first comments suggests, although the solution there did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

**How to delete an SD CARD**

Hi,

... try the "dd" command. It securely overwrites all with zeros. First, get the device by :

`sudo fdisk -l` 
Your device will be something like **sdX**.
(sdX --> only an example device name)

and be sure to identify the **right device**. Then use "dd" to overwrite the sd card with ZEROs:

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX`

While dd is working  on your sd card, you won't see a progress bar , so wait until dd has finished :o)

alternatively try this "shred" command (it takes time !!!):

```
sudo shred -vfz -n 100 /dev/sdX
```

You will find [here](http://www.techheadz.co.uk/189.html) an example, how to use "shred" with sd cards.

Kind regards