# Unable to delete file from read-only file system

Tags: permissions, read-only

I cannot delete files, when I tried to delete the file, this message appeard:

> "Error while deleting. There was an error deleting file2.rar."

This is what I get from clicking on *SHOW MORE DETAILS*:

> "Error removing file: Read-only file system"

This is what I've tried so far:

- deleting from the downloads directory from my user.
- deleting permanently, but it does not work.

**EDIT**

When trying to remount it as read/write I get this error:

```
 ~$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/A88F-8788  
 [sudo] password for name:  
 sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/jianyue/1: Read-only file system  
 mount: can't find /media/A88F-8788 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

I heard it is one of the bugs, waiting to be fixed.

**Just another edit on 2014**

No information about the resolution of the bug. I've not tried it again since then, because I have re-installed the system and misplaced files.

Comment: Please see possible duplicate question: [How to delete/edit files from read-only filesystem?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31614/how-to-delete-edit-files-from-readonly-filesystem)

Comment: You just copied the remount command from the other question. The path at the end has to point to the folder where that filesystem is mounted.

Comment: I tried the command from another question, it does not work. So, I am asking the public, how to fix it.

Comment: @tech What @stonedsquirrel is saying is that you need to change the  `/media/A88F-8788` part of the command to the partition that you want to change the permissions for. The OP of the linked question's partition was named `A88F-8788` but yours will be different. Use `mount -l` to find out what the partition name is and replace the `/media/A88F-8788` part of the command. For example, I have `/dev/sda4 on /media/123 type ext4 (rw)`, I'd use `sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/123` . That should work